# PHP Script not executing second command

Tags: php, if-statement, insert

I have a script where which inserts 2 notifications into a database table but it's only adding the first note and not the second. I've tried swapping them around and it still only posts the first of the 2. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$type = "---";
$title = "---";
$note1 = "Note 1";
$note2 = "Note 2";
?>
<?php
if($business1 !== ""){
    $insert_note1_sql = "INSERT INTO notes (id, recipient, type, title, post, message, date) VALUES('$id', 'Business 1', '$type', '$title', '$event', '$note1', '$time')";
    $insert_note1_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_note1_sql);
};
?>
<?php
if($business2 !== ""){
    $insert_note2_sql = "INSERT INTO notes (id, recipient, type, title, post, message, date) VALUES('$id', 'Business 2', '$type', '$title', '$event', '$note2', '$time')";
    $insert_note2_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_note2_sql);
};
?>
```

Can anyone see why the second not is not posted (They both !=="")?

Comment: You need to learn how to use error handlers.

Comment: Why do you keep closing and opening php tags? There's no html so there's no reason to do that.

Comment: @LiamSorsby Business 2 is a variable that is being passed through JQuery Post, I know this is being passed

Comment: @user2737457 do you grab it as a `$_POST['business1']` before trying to use it?

Comment: Whats wrong with if(!empty($business2)){//code}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the `id` field is a primary key field, and since you're using the same `$id` in both queries for the insertion, you're getting a duplicate key violation.

You should check the return values for failure, e.g.

```
$insert_note1_res = mysqli_query(...);
if ($insert_note1_res === FALSE) {
   die(mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: Ah yes of course, I've amended it to produce an $id2 and all is working fine now

Comment: @user2737457 you really should let your primary key auto increment.

Answer (score 1):

try using this statement in both the insert queries

```
$insert_note1_sql = "INSERT INTO notes (recipient, type, title, post, message, date) VALUES('Business 1', '$type', '$title', '$event', '$note1', '$time')";
```

and  `$insert_note2_sql = "INSERT INTO notes (recipient, type, title, post, message, date) VALUES('Business 2', '$type', '$title', '$event', '$note2', '$time')";`
and see if it works fine then...if it is working fine now then it means that the issue is of the primary key which is your ID

Answer (score 0):

`IF` statements don't use `;`

```
if($business2 !== ""){
    $insert_note2_sql = "INSERT INTO notes (id, recipient, type, title, post, message, date) VALUES('$id', 'Business 2', '$type', '$title', '$event', '$note2', '$time')";
    $insert_note2_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_note2_sql);
}; // <--------- ISSUE
```

**Proper way**

```
<?php
$type = "---";
$title = "---";
$note1 = "Note 1";
$note2 = "Note 2";

echo $business1;

if($business1 !== ""){
    $insert_note1_sql = "INSERT INTO notes (id, recipient, type, title, post, message, date) VALUES('$id', 'Business 1', '$type', '$title', '$event', '$note1', '$time')";
    $insert_note1_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_note1_sql);
}

echo $business2;

if($business2 !== ""){
    $insert_note2_sql = "INSERT INTO notes (id, recipient, type, title, post, message, date) VALUES('$id', 'Business 2', '$type', '$title', '$event', '$note2', '$time')";
    $insert_note2_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_note2_sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had it without the ; before and it wasn't working so I added them to see if it made a difference

Comment: @user2737457 try echoing `$business1` and `$business2` right before the `IF`s. Check out the edit in my post